# How to convert shipment pdf to rtl direction?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

I am trying to convert the pdf direction, to RTL.

Any one know how i can do this or any extension that will help to do this Quickly.

Comment: have you got any solution for this? Even I am trying to do the same thing. Please post here if you got anything related to this.